# Ripping audio CDs under Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: cd-ripping

ripping of audio CDs does not work on my Ubuntu 16.04 PC since I installed it. I installed all codecs (I am aware of) as well as "restricted extras". Any audio CD is recognized when inserted and played well by both VLC and Rhythmbox. But both Asunder and Sound Juicer do not show any content of the CD (i.e. artist, tracks, etc.).

With 12.04-based elementary OS ("Luna") being installed in another partition on the same box Asunder works perfectly and ripping CDs has never been an issue.

Does anybody know how to fix this?
thx in advance
Ulrich

Comment: Had the same problem myself with `Asunder` where Track Names had to be entered manually. After ripping had to use `Kid3` to get albumn artwork applied and even it didn't automatically get track names from the internet.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix - it is not just that Asunder would not get track information etc. It does not even recognize that there is a CD at all. Same with Sound Juicer.  With other applications the CD-drive (LG multi format r/w) works well. I really need to boot the old 12.04-based eOS in another partition to rip a CD.

Comment: My memory is a little foggy on this one but I **think** Ubuntu 14.04 it worked ok. I just tried asunder website looking for faq's but it timed out.

Comment: Works OK for me but I use [k3b](https://userbase.kde.org/K3b).

Answer (score 1):

There is a really easy way to rip a cd on linux without any extra software.

Open the cd folder, right-click on the file you want to rip, and click copy. 
Then open the folder you want to copy the track into, right-click and click paste.

**Tip:To select more than one file, hold control while clicking.**

Comment: yeah but you need to convert those .wavs to .mp3 afterwards